# What are some skills that can hit targets outside their range?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are quite a few skills that I know of that can hit units outside their range, for example, Azir's Soldiers and Lucian's Q.

**Are there any other skills that can do this?**

Also I feel that Xerath's Q hitbox is longer than the range indicator, sometimes I catch people at the end of my Q even if they were seemingly out of my Q's range.
 **Is Xerath's Q range longer than the indicator?**

Comment: As it is written, the title suggests you're not interested in a complete list, but rather in several examples, which would encourage many short answer giving single examples. That would thus make the question too broad.

Comment: i can comment that the amount of skillshots that extend beyond their indicator is for easines and how the game Works, the list isn't really long and the champions that use this are really few the extra distance is in most cases neglilible and is because of colision detection,  i dont think this comment is enough for an answer, but the ones i can remember for now is nautilus, thresh ahri and sivir

Comment: Because of the camera angle it's possible that most if not all skillshots have a little extra range than what the indicator shows

Comment: That edit should not have been approved.  It changed the intent of the question beyond what the asker wanted.  The only one who can approve those edits is the asker themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most cases Riot tries to keep the range indicator as accurate as possible. I do not know all but a few that I know are Nidalee's spear and Vi's Q. Blitzcrank's Q has a smaller animation, so it looks like the skillshot is smaller than it it. This is only valid on the I-Blitzcrank skin though. This is also the same for the Underworld Twisted Fate skin and the Santa Gragas skin. I do not know if Xerath's Q has a bigger hitbox then its range indicator. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I can think of these:

-Lissandra's Q (shatters past first target)

-Sion's E (Through minions)

-Velkoz's Q can travel further if fired at a right angle

-Viktor's E/Rumble's Ultimate can hit outside of it's indicated range

-Urgot's Q gets increased range when homing.

-Nami's W can bounce outside of the range of her indicator (if used on an ally it can bounce to an enemy far away).

-Master Yi's Q can hit enemies outside of range by bouncing through minions.

-Miss Fortune's Q can bounce outside of the initial range (although it does have a separate range indicator for the bounce).

A couple I wasn't sure about:

-Syndra's E's range indicator is accurate (when considering the knock back effect on champions) but the knocked back dark spheres can travel beyond the range indicator)

-LeBlanc's E's tether will break outside of a certain range, but until it has connected with a target it will not break (so you can Distortion in, cast chains, distortion out and the chains will still connect even though it is outside the range it should be).