# Does skins in League of legends affect the damage and others?

Tags: league-of-legends

I wanna know becuase this could change how the game is played and result in more people buying skins just for extra  damage and a little advantage in the game.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213011/which-skins-give-a-small-advantage

Comment: This question might be slightly different, as it's asking about stat changes where the linked question is asking about visual changes.

Comment: Those "easter egg" stat changes are so insignificant, there's a one in a million chance that the outcome of a fight would be affected. No one buys skins solely for the "damage boost" they may or may not receive. Or, if they are, those people are probably just desperate to get out of Bronze. ;)

Answer (score 6):

For the most part, no, there aren't any real changes to in-game stats from skins. However, certain skins have hidden passives that cause extremely minor changes, like characters receiving one less damage from Leona's Sunlight ability if they're wearing sunglasses. A list of hidden passives can be found [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Easter_eggs/Hidden_Passive).

Answer (score 0):

No, but there's the animation that can change the hitbox visibility, like Ezreal's Puslfire Skin makes his Q ability easier* to dodge.

You can look at this for a more detailed information about this:

[Which Skins give a small advantage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213011/which-skins-give-a-small-advantage)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some skins have this kind of effects, but it's easter eggs.
For example all skins with sunglasses take 1 damage less from Leona's ultimate (protection against sun rays)
Theese easter eggs are the only admitted bonus a skin can grant ingame.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually some skins that have advantages. For example iBlitzcrank is banned in pro matches just as Heartseeker Ashe, due to their abilities being harder to see. This would lead into giving the players an unfair advantage.